# flutter how to open txt file with open with dialog to specific page?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm new on flutter and never used intent filter. so far I have everything working in my app. but I'm stuck in importing the file to app by open with dialog. I need the user when it click on the file it will go to the page and display the information in the file. I'm using ImportFile plugin and it work fine but it make it harder for the users to put the file they receive. 
my app is list it in the open with dialog but when i click it, it just open the app **I want it to open the app and view the text in the view text page not the homepage**

AndroidManifest.xml
    <

```
intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
                </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
                        <data android:pathPattern="*.*\\.txt" />
                    </intent-filter>
```

MainActivity.java

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
                handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
            }
        }

        new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), "app.channel.shared.data").setMethodCallHandler(new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMethodCall(MethodCall methodCall, MethodChannel.Result result) {
                if (methodCall.method.contentEquals("getSharedText")) {
                    result.success(sharedText);
                    sharedText = null;
                }
            }
        });
    }


    void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
        sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

FlutterView has a setInitialRoute method you can use to specify a non-default route on launch.

Comment: Thank you for replaying, is there any code example?